# Unknown column in field list during select query

Tags: exception

I used the below query in my Java program

```
String getQTY="Select

Qty from available_stock WHERE Items='"+ itemName+"';";

ResultSet iset=stat.executeQuery(getQTY);
```

But it give the error like below
Unknown column Qty in the field list

Answer (score 0):

Try to get DESC from available_stock

```
DESC available_stock;
```

Check to see if Qty is present. If it is present, remove the extra **;** from your code.

```
String getQTY="Select Qty from available_stock WHERE Items='"+itemName+"'";
```

Comment: The same query is working at the database at the xampp server but not in my program. It gives the error in program and the Qty is existing in the available_ stock table

Comment: Try giving "select Qty from databasename.available_stock where Items='"+ itemName+"'";